# max frequency in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables (mysql)

1. tbl_products
2. tbl_counting

I have collected "rack" & "stock" information by 3 users in tbl_counting table.
I want to update "tbl_products.rack" & "tbl_products.stock" with tbl_counting data
with this condition (like Result):

- Each "Rack" & "Stock" information must be collected by at least 3 users
- tbl_products.rack" & "tbl_products.stock" must update with highest frequency (At least 2 times) of "Rack" or "Stock" information
- If "Rack" or "Stock" information was repeated less than 2 times, specify field with "Unknow". (like result)

Thanks

**1. tbl_products** (befor update)

| id | product_name | rack | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |  |  |
| 2 | orange |  |  |
| 3 | strawberry |  |  |

**2. tbl_counting**

| product_id | user_id | rack | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A-1-1 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | A-1-1 | 10 |
| 1 | 3 | B-1-1 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | C-1-1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | D-2-1 | 30 |
| 2 | 3 | A-3-1 | 30 |
| 3 | 1 | X-3-1 | 25 |
| 3 | 2 | X-1-1 | 10 |
| 3 | 3 | X-3-1 | 25 |

Result: **tbl_products**(after UPDATE)

| id | product_name | rack | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | **A-1-1** | **20** |
| 2 | orange | **Unknown** | **30** |
| 3 | strawberry | **X-3-1** | **25** |

```
select 
tbl_counting.product_id,
tbl_counting.rack,
MAX(tbl_counting.stock),
count(*) as freq
from tbl_counting 

group by tbl_counting.product_id
having count(*) =(select max(freq) 
from (select product_id,count(*) as freq 
from tbl_counting group by product_id) tbl_counting)
```

Comment: What did you try to solve this? Where did it stop ? Why did it stop there ? what (exactly) is going wrong ?  Why does someone else need to solve your (home)work ?

Comment: Why does `apple` get a stock of 20 and not 10? Both rows have `A-1-1` as the `rack`

Comment: Where do we find the rack `Unknown` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution. The first two cte gets you the count of users and distinct racks by product, which are used in the next cte to filter the records that meet the given criteria.

```
UPDATE tbl_products P
JOIN (
    WITH uses_count AS
    (
        SELECT product_id,              
               COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS num_users         
        FROM tbl_counting 
        GROUP BY product_id
    )
    , rack_count AS
    (
        SELECT product_id,   
               rack,
               COUNT(*) AS freq         
        FROM tbl_counting 
        GROUP BY product_id, rack
    )
    ,rank_result AS 
    (
      SELECT T.product_id,
             T.rack,
             T.stock,
             R.freq,
             U.num_users,                 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.product_id ORDER BY R.freq DESC, T.stock DESC) AS RN
      FROM tbl_counting T
      LEFT JOIN uses_count U
        ON T.product_id = U.product_id
           AND CASE WHEN U.num_users >= 3 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
      LEFT JOIN rack_count R
        ON T.product_id = R.product_id
           AND CASE WHEN R.freq >= 2 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END  
    )
    SELECT product_id, 
           stock,               
           CASE WHEN freq IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE rack END AS rack
    FROM  rank_result
    WHERE RN = 1) R
  ON P.Id = R.product_id
SET P.stock = R.stock,
    P.rack = R.rack
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE tbl_products P
JOIN rank_result R 
  ON P.Id = R.product_id
     AN...' at line 34

Comment: Try if the updated query works.

Comment: Unknown column 'R.freq' in 'field list'

Comment: Try now. It was missing in one of the ctes.

Comment: Unknown column 'R.c' in 'field list'

Comment: Get the latest query, which I posted a couple of minutes ago. There is no R.c field in the query.

Comment: thanks dear, did you test query ? 
Unknown column 'R.freq' in 'field list'
R.freq in lines 23,25,32,36

Comment: Try it one more time. Also, make sure to tag your questions correctly. The first version of the query was tested and running fine in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You Can check this

```
SELECT
    product_id p,
    shelf,
    floor,
    line,
    stock 
FROM
    user_product 
GROUP BY
    product_id,
    stock,
    floor,
    line,
    shelf
HAVING
    stock = ( SELECT stock FROM user_product WHERE product_id = p GROUP BY stock ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1 ) AND
    floor = ( SELECT floor FROM user_product WHERE product_id = p GROUP BY floor ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1 ) AND
    line = ( SELECT line FROM user_product WHERE product_id = p GROUP BY line ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1 ) AND
    shelf = ( SELECT shelf FROM user_product WHERE product_id = p GROUP BY shelf ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1 );
```